# Sankey Diagram with networkD3 package miximises CPU usage and does not show the diagram

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

Most times I try plot a Sankey diagram in `R` my CPU is maximised and the diagram does not show. Does anyone know what could be causing this? My computer is decent with i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz 2.90GHZ. To get the CPU back down again I have been having to restart `R`.

For example I was using this example code

```
library("networkD3")

myDf <- list(
    nodes=data.frame(name=c( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
                             "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")),
    links=data.frame(source=as.integer(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)),
                     target=as.integer(c(7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 9)),
                     value =           c(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3)
    )
)

sankeyNetwork(Links = myDf$links, Nodes = myDf$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 25, nodeWidth = 30, 
              fontFamily = "sans-serif", iterations = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with your package or R Studio configuration.

Try saving the sankeyNetwork as an HTML file using the `saveNetwork()` command from the same package (networkD3) and opening that.

e.g.

```
library("networkD3")

myDf <- list(
    nodes=data.frame(name=c( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
                             "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")),
    links=data.frame(source=as.integer(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)),
                     target=as.integer(c(7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5, 9)),
                     value =           c(1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 3)
    )
)

sk <- sankeyNetwork(Links = myDf$links, Nodes = myDf$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 25, nodeWidth = 30, 
              fontFamily = "sans-serif", iterations = 0)

saveNetwork(sk,file = "sk.html")
```